# Creating a scene with multiple graphs at once

Tags: python-3.x, manim

Many different disciplines, Physics or Economics, for instance, require displaying multiple graphs at once, usually one on top of each other in order to demonstrate how some shock or event impacts different variables. 
How could this be done in Manim?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, let's paste the solution's code.

```
class PlotTwoGraphsAtOnce(GraphScene):
CONFIG = {
    "y_max" : 40,
    "y_min" : 0,
    "x_max" : 7,
    "x_min" : 0,
    "y_tick_frequency" : 10,
    "x_tick_frequency" : 1,
    "x_axis_width": 6,
    "y_axis_height": 3,
    "axes_color" : GRAY, 
}
def construct(self):
    self.graph_origin = -0.5 * DOWN + 3 * LEFT
    self.setup_axes(animate=True)
    graph_up = self.get_graph(lambda x : x**2, 
                                color = GOLD_A,
                                x_min = 0, 
                                x_max = 3
                                )
    f1 = TexMobject(r"f(x) = {x}^2", color = GOLD_A)
    f1.scale(0.7)
    label_coord1 = self.input_to_graph_point(3,graph_up)
    f1.next_to(label_coord1,RIGHT+UP)
    self.graph_origin = 3.5 * DOWN + 3 * LEFT
    self.setup_axes(animate=True)
    graph_down = self.get_graph(lambda x : x**3, 
                                color = BLUE_D,
                                x_min = 0, 
                                x_max = 3
                                )
    graphs=VGroup(graph_up,graph_down)
    f2 = TexMobject(r"f(x) = {x}^3", color = BLUE_D)
    f2.scale(0.7)
    label_coord2 = self.input_to_graph_point(3,graph_up)
    f2.next_to(label_coord2,RIGHT+UP)
    self.play(
        ShowCreation(graphs),
        run_time = 2,
    )
    self.play(ShowCreation(f1), ShowCreation(f2))
    self.wait(3)
```

And here's a visual preview of the final result.

[image: x**2 and x**3 displayed in two graphs, one of top of the other]

For the implementation of this solution I took inspiration from [this](https://github.com/3b1b/manim/issues/331#issuecomment-478040077) answer.

Comment: How could I draw the two curves simultaneously instead of one after the other?

Comment: Replying to my own question above, just need to not play them as a VGroup, i.e.,  replace ShowCreation(graphs) with ShowCreation(graph_up), ShowCreation(graph_down)